# libgit2sharp Diff of Tree with a not saved file

Tags: libgit2sharp

I would like to extend GitDiffMargin addin so that when a user is modifying a file in Visual Studio she can see the update diff in the margin even without saving the file.

Is it possible with libgit2sharp to do such a diff from a Tree and another Tree which I would have to build myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, this question can be splitted into 3 sub questions:

- How to diff two Trees
- How to build a new Tree by modifying an existing one file (Blob) from it
- How to create a Blob from the content of a file that hasn't been previously saved to disk.

**How to diff two Trees:**

- API: [repo.Diff.Compare<T>(Tree, Tree)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Diff.cs#L114-L126)
- Tests: [DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs)

**How to build a new Tree by modifying an existing one file (Blob) from it:**

- API: [TreeDefinition.From(Tree)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/TreeDefinition.cs#L19-L24), [TreeDefinition.Add(string, Blob, Mode)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/TreeDefinition.cs#L155-L162) and [repo.ObjectDatabase.CreateTree(TreeDefinition)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/ObjectDatabase.cs#L172-L177)
- Tests: [TreeDefinitionFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TreeDefinitionFixture.cs) and [ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs)

**How to create a Blob from the content of a file that hasn't been previously saved to disk:**

- API: [CreateBlob(Stream, string)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/ObjectDatabase.cs#L150-L157)
- Tests: [ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs#L79-L145)

Comment: Is there another way than CreateBlob which would not triggers changes to the repository? I am facing the current [issue described here](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin/issues/22). Thanks for your help

Comment: @LaurentKempé I've fed the issue with some thoughts.